# How to affix an implicit curried parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, slick, scalaz

I'm using a DAO library (ActiveSlick) with the following method signatures:

```
def save(entity: Entity)(implicit exc: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Entity]
```

etc. Most have an implicit curried `exc` param.

I'm extending the class, and want to affix the ExecutionContext to something predefined, e.g.: `implicit val context = Contexts.dbContext`.

Also, I've wrapped the pure methods in a:

```
 def run[S] (action: DBIO[S]): Future[Try[S]] =  db.run(action.asTry)
```

Yet the implicit context doesn't get picked up by the client code.

What I could do is this:

```
def run[S] (action: ExecutionContext => DBIO[S]): Future[Try[S]] =  db.run(action(context).asTry)
```

Yet this is ugly, since I have to explicitly curry in the client code:

```
dao.run (dao.insert(entity)(_))
```

My question is whether I could affix the implicit `ExecutionContext` parameter in my class, so that the calls are always clean(er):

```
dao.run (dao.insert (entity))
```

I heard the `Reader` monad can do something like that.. but grokking it is proving rather hard.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't want to override all the methods, but find a generic solution to the problem. By overriding I mean e.g.: `override def insert (entity: Entity)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext) = super.insert(entity)(context)`

Comment: sorry, def should be: `... (implicit ctx: ExecutionContext = someDefinedCtx)`

Answer (score 0):

Define a trait like below and mix it wherever you need it:

```
trait ExeContext {
  implicit def exe: ExecutionContext
  //Methods that use the implicit exe
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't propagate the implicit to the method call-site. One complication can be that I was describing a base class, but I also added an implicit context in the descendants - and still it was missing at the call-site. So short of importing it every time I couldn't find another solution.